# magic mock set value for attribute only get the first value

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, magicmock

I am using pytest3.7 to test. I would like to mock `res`,which is return value from `get_res_function`. `res.property1[key1][keyN].property2` is the value I want to mock. Here is my test:

```
@mock.patch("mypkg.get_res_function")
def test_function(mock_res):
    returner = mock.MagicMock()
    returner.property1["key1"]["key2"].property2 = "11111"
    returner.property1["key1"]["key3"].property2 = "22222"
    mock_res.return_value = returner
```

However, both values i want to mock only use the first line mock's value, which means `mock_res.property1["key1"]["key2"].property2 = "11111", mock_res_property1["key1"]["key3"].property2 = "11111"`
and if reverse it in test code, meaning put "22222" before "11111",

```
returner.property1["key1"]["key2"].property2 = "22222"
        returner.property1["key1"]["key3"].property2 = "11111"
```

then all the results is "22222", what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky because the item access syntax `thing[index]` is actually calling the magic method `__getitem__`, and that's what you want to mock.

So this

```
returner.property1["key1"]["key2"].property2 = "11111"
```

Is like doing this

```
returner.property1.__getitem__.return_value.__getitem__.return_value.property2 = "11111"
```

Which is ok, since it's a bit more concise, however the keys are actually ignored.

You can use a `PropertyMock` with `side_effect` to return different things in order:

```
type(returner.property1.__getitem__.return_value.__getitem__.return_value).property2 = PropertyMock(side_effect=["11111", "22222"])
```

Or, back to get item syntax:

```
type(returner.property1["this is"]["ignored"]).property2 = PropertyMock(side_effect=["11111", "22222"])
```

And it should work:

```
returner.property1["foo"]["bar"].property2
> '11111'
returner.property1["foo"]["bar"].property2
> '22222'
```

However, keep in mind that it will return the same values regardless of the input keys. And it will raise `StopIteration` if it runs out of `side_effects`.

You can assert which keys are actually used to call `__getitem__`:

```
returner.property1.__getitem__.call_args_list
returner.property1.__getitem__.return_value.__getitem__.call_args_list
```

If you prefer, you could pass a function as `side_effect` instead, it would be called with the same arguments as the mock (the key) and then you could decide what to return depending on the key. But this would need to be done in the `__getitem__` mock, not the property mock.

Some references:

- `__getitem__`:
  [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getitem**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)
- `PropertyMock`:
  https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock
- `side_effect`:
  https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect